# IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: '' Exception in Tkinter callback

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

We are trying to get a file path from an explorer window in Windows, but when we run our class to use the file path, it crashes with the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: ''Exception in Tkinter callback
```

I think the error is something to do with how we store the file path

Here is our code:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
import subprocess
import sys
import tkFileDialog
import PIL
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # single use of plt is commented out
import os.path  
import PIL.ImageDraw        
import PIL.Image

bg_size   = [1080,1920]
logo_size = [200,200]
seal_size = [200,200]

wink = ""
wow = ""
seal = 0

class Political_Logo:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="Picture Logo")
        self.label.pack()

        self.label = Label(master, text="Banner")
        self.label.pack()

        self.find_button = Button(master, text="Find Campaign Background", command=self.OpenExplorer)
        self.find_button.pack()

        self.find_button = Button(master, text="Find Campaign Logo", command=self.OpenExplorer1)
        self.find_button.pack()

        self.find_button = Button(master, text="Lets Go", command=lambda: self.test(wow,wink))
        self.find_button.pack()

    def OpenExplorer(self):
        def main():

            Tkinter.Tk().withdraw() # Close the root window
            in_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
            wow = in_path
            print wow , "\n"
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            main()
    def OpenExplorer1(self):
        def main():

            Tkinter.Tk().withdraw() # Close the root window
            in_path1 = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
            wink = in_path1
            print wink , "\n"

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            main()

    def find_filename(substring, self):
        import os
        import re
        files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
        for file in files:
            search = re.search(substring, file)
            if search:
                filename = file
                break
        return filename



    def test(main_image, logo_image, self):
        logo_image = PIL.Image.open(logo_image, 'r')
        main_image = PIL.Image.open(main_image, 'r')
        img_w, img_h = main_image.size

        if seal == 0:
            print("We converting a banner its lit")
            offset = (0,780)
            main_image.paste(logo_image, offset)
            main_image.save('out.png')
            main_image.show()
        else:
            logo_image.resize(seal_size)
            offset = (0,600)
            print("We are converting a seal over here")



root = Tk()
my_gui = Political_Logo(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is our stack trace:

```
File "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\1.4.7-Project\GUI.py", line 41, in <lambda>
    self.find_button = Button(master, text="Lets Go", command=lambda: self.test(wow,wink))
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\1.4.7-Project\GUI.py", line 69, in test
    logo_image = PIL.Image.open(wow, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\User\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2288, in open
    fp = builtins.open(fp, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: ''
Exception in Tkinter callback
```

Comment: Where is the code that actually calls `find_filename`?

Comment: That's our old code that we saved just in case. It doesn't really matter. The code that we run to get the file name is the OpenExplorer function. It then saves it into a variable called wow. Then we run the command, feeding in the path variables.

Comment: If "it doesn't really matter" it shouldn't be included in the question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You save filenames into a local variable called `wow`, not the global variable called `wow`. Add `global wow` to the top of the functions that write the variable. BTW, if there is a full stack trace, please post it so we know the line the error is on.

Comment: I initialized the variables as     global wink and global wow and it does the same thing. I added the stack trace too

Comment: The error message is telling you your filename is an empty string. You are storing the filename in a local variable, so no other function will be able to see it.

Comment: Tkinter likely won't behave the way you expect when you create more than one root window.